# Instantiation of norm bound in SIS

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, sis

Recall Short Integer Solution:

$\textbf{SIS}_{n, q, \beta, m}$: Given $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}_q$, $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, find $\vec{z} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m}$ of norm $||z|| \le \beta$ s.t. $\textbf{A}\vec{z} = \vec{b}$.

We must take $\beta < q$ to avoid trivial solutions and $\beta \ge \sqrt{n \log q}$ to guarantee that a solution exists. Is there any other conditions of $\beta$. In particular, is it secure to set $\beta = q-1$?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too close. [MP13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/069) gives the tighest reduction I know of from other lattice problems. It works for any $q \geq \beta \cdot n^\delta$ for some constant $\delta > 0$.

If you let $\beta(n) = q(n) - 1$, then
$$
q(n) \geq \beta(n) \cdot n^\delta
\iff 
q(n)/n^\delta \geq q(n) - 1
$$
But $q(n) / n^\delta < q(n) - 1$ when $n^\delta \geq 2$ and $q(n) > 2$, which is the case for all sufficiently large $n$. So the reduction doesn't go through.